# SpringBoot + hibernate 5 MVC BasicDataSource UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, google-cloud-platform

Hi I'm trying to set up spring boot mvc project with hibernate (further on gcp)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dirtangel.miodigy"})
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext
                = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.setConfigLocation("com.dirtangel.miodigy.config");
        rootContext.register(HibernateConf.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext
                = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(HibernateConf.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher
                = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:hibernate.properties"})
@EntityScan("com.dirtangel.miodigy.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.dirtangel.miodigy.repo")
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dirtangel.miodigy"})
public class HibernateConf implements WebMvcConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware {
@Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class[]{Hustler.class});
        sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(applicationContext.getResource("classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"));

        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"com.dirtangel.miodigy", "com.dirtangel.miodigy.entity"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();


        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/miodigy");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("postgres");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl");

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/miodigy");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "postgres");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "postgres");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.packageToScan", "com.dirtangel.miodigy.entity");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", "false");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.dirtangel.miodigy.HibernateConf: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>           
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>            
        </dependency>  
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>    
            <scope>test</scope>        
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>    
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>           
        </dependency>
         
        <!-- The Postgresql JDBC driver dependency -->       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate core dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You have way too many dependencies in pom.xml The best way to start with is to generate pom.xml on this page: https://start.spring.io/ Choose Maven and add only relevant dependencies like Spring Web, Spring Data JPA, PostgreSQL Driver. Using this starters the whole hard work of configuration will be done by Spring auto-magically. You can just start coding you entities and Rest controller.

Comment: ok. cool. thanks for an advise. I acutally added something I also wanted to my pom.xml

Comment: the solution of the problem was different thou ```@Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(); ... }```